# detecting dot or comma in a regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
 preg_match_all("/^\\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|ribu|(?:\\.\\d{3})+|\\d+)$/m", 'Ini harga barangnya ya sis @26.000 banget', $matches);
```

This works fine for extracting 26.000 however if I have 26,000 this doesn't work.
How do I modify this so that it works for dot and comma? I don't want to change the other semantics in the regex

Here's a [working sample regex](http://regex101.com/r/bL8nO3/3). I wanted so that it also matches 26,000 in that regex without breaking the other already matching regex

Comment: @hwnd so this should be put in between \\ \\, and now it becomes \\[.,]\\d{3} ?

Comment: @Class mind posting an answer? As it is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|ribu|(?:[,.]\d{3})+|\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/4

http://regex101.com/r/bL8nO3/4

Comment: I tried this preg_match_all("/^\\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|ribu|(?:[,.]\d{3})+|\\d+)$/m", "Ini harga barangnya ya sis 26k banget", $matches); and matches returns an array of 0 length, why?

Comment: @adit, use a character class and remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @adit just saw ur input.as hwnd said remove the anchors.